# C#: Initialize Random() only once in a singleton pattern

Tags: c#, random, singleton

I am trying to initialize only once a random variable, let's say 'rnd'. So If from many points of my program it is called, then the random variable will not be initialized again, only first time.

So I have created a singleton but I do not know how to call only once Random().

```
public sealed class Randomize
{
    private static Randomize instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Randomize()
    {
    }
    public static Randomize Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Randomize();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within this class I would like to create a private readonly random variable, 'rnd', which is initialized only once, the first time, to:

```
Random rnd = new Random()
```

Then, I would like to create a property to read its value, for example:

```
        public Random Rnd
        {
            get { return rnd; }
        }
```

I do not want to allow to change its value because it is assigned first time only, so I only want the property to be readonly (get), not set.

So from many points of my program I can do:

```
private readonly Random rnd;
Random rnd = Randomize.Instance.Rnd;
```

But each time I call it using above expression I do not want to initizalize random variable again (by doing new Random()) instead I want to always obtain the same value it was rnd variable was initialized for first time.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: `Random` is not designed to be manipulated from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Look at Skeet's [article on singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: what is not working? where is the `new Random()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a static constructor, by definition that is gaurenteed to only be called once

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) Documentation States :

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

```
public sealed class Randomize
{
    private static Randomize instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public Random GetRandom { get { return rnd; } }        

    private static readonly Random rnd;

    static Randomize()
    {
        rnd = new Random();
    }
}
```

Comment: but here you can call Randomize multiple times from different points of the program, and each time a new instance of Random is obtained. I only want to initialize Random() once, and next times I do not want to initialize again, only obtain the initialized Random() at first time.

Comment: @user1624552 No The Static Constructor on the randomize class is only Initialize once it is not a normal constructor.

Comment: Please read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) Documentation'

Comment: Ok, sorry. So if I call it from many points of my program, for example: Random r1 = Randomize.GetRandom; Random r2 = Randomize.GetRandom; then r1 and r2, r3, r4 and so on will have the same value, right?

Comment: yes, the Random variable will only be initialize once before any reference to the static class is class

Comment: static is missed on private readonly Random rnd. It should be  private static readonly Random rnd; please correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `Randomize.Random` with the following snippet and it will always return the once-initialized `Random rnd` field.

```
public sealed class Randomize {
    private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    public static Random Random {
       get {
           return rnd;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read only variables can be assigned in the constructor, so I would go that route.

```c#
public sealed class Randomize {
    /* access level here */ Random rnd { get { return r; } }
    private readonly Random r;

    static Randomize() {
        r = new Random();
    }
}

// or

        private readonly Random r = new Random();
        public Random rnd {
            get {
                return r;
            }
        }
```